# What is SMT + DIP? (shell through hole)

Tags: pcb, usb, connector, surface-mount, dip

[Hirose](http://hirose.com/) offers a Micro-B USB receptacle ZX62D-B-5PA8 as *SMT + DIP*.
This doesn't really make sense to me, considering that the electronic
contacts are SMD and the mechanical pins are just 0.8mm deep, less than
many PCB. I verified the pin depth in the [IGES 3D model](http://www.hirose-connectors.com/connectors/3d_download01.aspx?T2=ZX62D-B-5PA8).

*How is this mounted, i.e. how are the mechanical pins utilized?*

Annotated screen shot showing receptacle in [catalog page](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/185/e24200011-37133.pdf):

[image: Screen shot of catalog page]

Annotated screen shot showing *SMT + DIP* in catalog's table of contents:

[image: Screen shot of catalog table of contents]

Comment: It seems like "DIP" is the wrong term for this.  dual-inline what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SMD offers very little mechanical strength, and there is a fairly common failure mode for SMD microUSB connectors.  Plated through holes for the case improve mechanical reliability.

Comment: +1.  Signal contacts are SMT, mechanical pins are throughole. This is not uncommon with USB connectors. In this case, "DIP" is a bit of a [Japanese?] misnomer. "SMT+throughole" would be more accurate.

Comment: But the mechanical pins are a bit short (0.8 mm) for through the hole, no?

Comment: @feklee  Long enough.  The pins will still hold the mechanical loads.  You can still solder them.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Thanks for clarification. Judging from the picture provided by Hirose, I assume that's right.